# How can I select VerticalBarSeries from a ReactVis series plot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-vis

ReactVis API [here](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/series-reference/bar-series) outlines what is available which might be helpful. I have successfully added a "drag to select" function to my custom code. In the picture, we would be selecting 13 to 17 and turn the `fill` value to `red` for example.

More pseudo code question but code would be awesome.[image]

A container `div` in a Hook would look like this:

```
<div className="unselectable"
  style={{ position: 'relative' }}
  onMouseDown={(e) => {
    if (!x && !y) {
      setX(e.clientX); setY(e.clientY)
    }
  }}
  onMouseMove={(e) => {
    if (x && y) {
      const newX = e.clientX; const newY = e.clientY;
      setX1(newX); setY1(newY);
      setRect(
        <div style={{
          zIndex: 10000,
          position: 'fixed',
          left: x > newX ? newX : x, top: y > newY ? newY : y,
          width: Math.abs(newX - x), height: Math.abs(newY - y),
          backgroundColor: 'gray', opacity: 0.2
        }} />
      )
    }
  }}
  onMouseUp={(e) => {
    setX(null); setY(null); setX1(null); setY1(null);
    setRect(null);
  }}
>
    <XYPlot>
        //...
    </XYPlot>
    {rect}
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This might be helpful
https://codesandbox.io/s/109xx5j08j

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve "selected" vs "notSelected" state of the series, we need to use "datawithcolor" objects as our data object: `{x: foo, y: bar, color:0}`. Passing such an array to a react-series would be sufficient to render different coloured series (bars for example). For example: `[{x: foo, y: bar, color:0}]` where `colorDomain` would be `[0, 1]` and the `colorRange` would be some `blue` and `red`.

In order to have a listed of selected "values", we can hold on to a list of values in a react state (hooks or class), either during a dragging of a rectangle or after the rectangle has been drawn, in my case only during dragging. Every time the rectangle changes, the list must be updated.

On re-render generate a new "datawithcolor" array for React-vis bar-series with colour ranges and domains defined using indexes returned from `onNearestX` or similar React-vis callback.

How do we update the `selected` list?

```
<ReactSeries
          // see React-vis source of abstract-series.js for details
          /*
          onNearestX(value, {
            innerX: xScaleFn(value),
            index: valueIndex,
            event: event.nativeEvent
          });
          */
          onNearestX={(datapoint, { index, innerX }) => {
            // rect is mentioned in the question
            if (rect && isWithinRect({ x, x1, value: innerX })) {
              if (!selected.includes(index)) { // prevent rerender
                setSelected([...selected, index]);
              }
            } else {
              if (!rect) {              
                setSelected([index]); // single hover
              }
            }
          }}
          colorDomain={[0, 1]}
          colorRange={['red', 'blue']}
          data={dataWithColor} />
```

For full example see [this](https://github.com/layik/eAtlas/blob/32df34da18c5ca98a9bf22ea8c71ca98caab658a/src/components/DeckSidebar/DeckSidebar.jsx).

Things to remember, managing the rectangle and selected list are two different things. React-vis colorRange should be clear by now, the docs were not so helpful to me.